# The webpage title that I get through chrome.tabs.onUpdated is inaccurate,Occasionally,

Tags: google-chrome-extension

It works on most websites, except https://www.google.com.hk:
The first time I open the page, Ican get the correct title, but when I start the search, each time the title is the last page's.
What's the problem??
this is my code:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(changeInfo.status == "complete"){
        console.log('title: ' + tab.title);
    }
});
```

Comment: Try reading changeInfo.title

Comment: What *exactly* do you see in the console? What, specifically, are you expecting to see?

Comment: @wOxxOm 'title' is not exist in changinfo : (

Comment: @Makyen I expect to get the title i see, but given the previous title I see.